# Which option to select on User Interface while starting iOS app development in Xcode 11? Swift UI or Storyboard?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uistoryboard, swiftui

I'm planning to develop a new Taxi Bookings managing app for Drivers on Xcode 11. Which is the best option to select from **User Interface** on start screen?
[image]

Comment: totally depends on your requirements. SwiftUI is iOS 13 only.

Comment: It's depends on you. How you want to code? With SwiftUI or Storyboard Design?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed it depends on you and how you want to learn the code.
Swiftui is a new framework that has just been released en every one is playing with it, Some people say that it will need some time to grow up..

On the other side if you start with storyboard you always have the option to combine the two so far if you ever want to or need to.

Playing with the new framework is a lot of fun! hope you found the answer you were looking for.